# How to iterate through a string array, creating an object per item?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, robo3t

I have the following model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    Name: String,
    Author: String,
    Library: String,
}, { collection: 'Books' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Books', schema);
```

I have an array containing book titles strings (bookTitles). I want to iterate through that list and for each title, create a new Book object. I plan to save that in a list so I may do an insertMany to Mongo. I plan to do this as follows:

```
const Books = require('../models/Books');
const booksToAdd = [];
    
bookTitles.forEach(bookTitle => booksToAdd.push(new Books({
            Title: bookTitle
            })))

console.log(booksToAdd);    
await Books.insertMany(booksToAdd);
```

I have properly set up mongoose locally and am able access the db with other services in this project. Currently, if I print the books array I get an undefined object which has me thinking I'm not properly adding the Book object to the books array. In which case adding to the Books collection wouldn't work anyways since I'm not actually adding anything. How should I be iterating through the bookTitles so to create an array of Books objects, which would be added to the mongo collection with insertMany?

Comment: It shouldn't be console logging an undefined object.  You have it defined as an empty array.  If it is logging as undefined, something else is going on that is not showin in the question, would be my assumption.

Comment: I updated the way I was logging. What is returned is not undefined, it is simply an empty array so then, as suspected I'm not adding to the array as I should be.

Comment: First step would be to verify that `bookTitles` has elements in it.

Comment: It does. It is non-empty and contains strings. As noted in another comment it's not any real bookTitles but if I log it in the console I get  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are almost there, i have no clue of mongo.

```
const Books = require('../models/Books');
const booksToAdd = [];
    
bookTitles.forEach(bookTitle => booksToAdd.push(new Books({
            Title: bookTitle
            })))
```

The one thing i am not sure of is why you are using booksToAdd.push(new Books

What makes sense to me is booksToAdd.push(new Object //works for my example data

```
const booksToAdd = [];
let bookTitles = ["first","second","third"];
bookTitles.forEach(bookTitle => booksToAdd.push(new Object({
            Title: bookTitle})))
 //booksToAdd
 // (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

0: {Title: "first"}1: {Title: "second"}2: {Title: "third"}length: 3__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Is there a way to do that where I'm creating a specific Books object in the forEach? The purpose of creating it at a Books object is for it to be in the popper format for MongoDB to recognize for the specific collection "Books"

Answer (score 0):

We cannot see any part of the code where you initialize the bookTitles property.
If there isn't, there isn't any iteration also. Provide us with more code.
Also try to put a console.log(bookTitles) before its forEach.

Comment: bookTitles is a parameter for this method. It is well defined and non-empty. When I do console.log(bookTitles) I get the following in the terminal: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]. Right now I'm testing it, not with any real book titles.